# Build issue in VSTS build agent on Mac (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

### Introduction

Basically, I'm not able to setup continuous integration for a Xamarin.iOS project using VSTS and xbuild on macOS.

### Current Setup

I've set up a VSTS build definition to build a very simple project (template actually) on a Mac Mini with the latest Apple macOS 10. Xamarin is installed and I was able to build and deploy a sample project onto my iPad. The same applies for XCode as well. Below is my whole continuous integration chain:

1. Upload code to Bitbucket
2. VSTS build definition gets notified about new change
3. VSTS build definition connects to the build agent on macOS
4. build agent builds the project

### Problem

The build always fails with the following message:

```
[error]XamariniOS task failed with error Error: Failed which: Not found xbuild: null.
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to find out what exactly failed. The source code is under `~/myagent/_work/1/s`. The solution file to be built is also there and I'm certain that this is found.

The build agent on macOS just reports:

```
Job build completed with result: Failed
```

### Actual Question

What is missing in my setup? Where can I get more info to track down that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message actually says that `xbuild` was not found on the build system. The solution is to provide the path to `xbuild` in the build task settings. There is an extra input field for that in the `Advanced` section.